# Translates of a fixed point set (of stable points) by a reductive group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

I have the following set up:

Suppose that I am working over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that I have a reductive group $G$ acting linearly on $V$, and that I have a $G$-invariant smooth affine variety $X$ in $V$. Suppose further, that $G$ acts on $X$ such that every orbit is closed, and stabilizers are finite (i.e. all points are properly stable). Assume that the action of $G$ on $X$ is generically free.

If $R$ is a finite subgroup of $G$, does anybody know if $GX^{R}$ is smooth?

If we do not assume that all stabilizers are finite, I know that $GX^{R}$ is smooth if $R$ is a connected reductive subgroup of $G$. This may be proved with Luna's slice theorem, and showing that the natural map $f: G *_{N_{G}(R)} X^{R} \rightarrow GX^{R} \subset X$ is etale. However, I cannot reproduce this argument, as it appears that the connectedness assumption was necessary.

Thank you very much, I appreciate any help.

P.S. I had already asked this on mathstackexchange a while back.. but received no responses.. So, I am trying it on here! Thank you.

EDIT: Forgot to say that X was smooth.. sorry.

Comment: Have you tried some examples -- maybe ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb C)$ acting on $n$ distinct points on $\mathbb P^1$ for some large $n$?

Comment: @LevBorisov Hi, thank you for the comment. I have tried some examples.. they seem to suggest that it is smooth, unless I am missing something simple here.. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to find counterexamples by "twisting" an action of a connected reductive group $G_0$ by a cyclic group $R$ of automorphisms of $G_0$.  This did not work, and that strongly suggests to me that $GX^R$ is, indeed, smooth.

Comment: I suggest looking at how the tangent subspaces $Lie(G)x$ and $T(x,X^R)$ intersect as $x$ varies in $X^R$. I would want to look at examples where the dimension of the intersection jumps at some $x$

Comment: @LevBorisov Thank you for the suggestion.. I can try that out.. so do you suspect that this will not be smooth in general? Thanks!

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for thinking about this. By a number of examples, I also thought that GX^R should be smooth in general.. However, I don't know how to prove it!

Comment: @Elliot I am not an expert -- maybe it could be singular.